# ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, linux

I am trying to run the below Pl/SQL statements on my Oracle DB 11g on Linux box, but getting the error "missing keyword". Please let me know if I miss anything.

```
BEGIN

FOR X in (select * from all_tables where owner in ('owner1', 'owner2')) LOOP

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ' ||X.owner||'.'||X.table_name|| 'to myuser';

END LOOP;

end;
/


Error starting at line : 1 in command -
BEGIN
FOR X in (select * from all_tables where owner in ('TESTDTA', 'TESTCTL')) LOOP
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ' ||X.owner||'.'||X.table_name|| 'to ARCTOOLS212';
END LOOP;

end;
```

Error report

> ORA-00905: missing keyword ORA-06512: at line 3
>
> 905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
>
> *Cause:
>
> *Action:

Answer (score 5):

there's a space missing before to in 'to myuser'.

```
BEGIN
FOR X in (select * from all_tables where owner in ('TESTDTA', 'TESTCTL'))
LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON '
        ||X.owner||'.'||X.table_name||
        ' to TESTUSER';
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Still same error:

Error starting at line : 8 in command -
BEGIN
FOR X in (select * from all_tables where owner in ('TESTDTA', 'TESTCTL')) LOOP
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ' ||X.owner||'.'||X.table_name|| 'to ARCTOOLS212';
END LOOP;
END;
Error report -
ORA-00905: missing keyword
ORA-06512: at line 3
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Comment: i don't see a space between ' and to.

Comment: @HanspeterOberlin: You are right and he is missing the space before the `TO` keyword thus making my answer inappropriate.

Comment: @Naveen - When you get an issue like this with dynamic sql try creating a VARCHAR2 variable, create your SQL into the variable and then use DBMS_OUTPUT to show what it is actually trying to execute. Problems usually show up pretty quickly.

Comment: Hi Hanspeter, i added space after ' and to, but still same issue
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
begin
   FOR x IN (SELECT * FROM all_tables WHERE OWNER IN ('CRPDTA')) LOOP
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON '|| x.owner ||'.'|| x.table_name || '  TO ARCTOOLS212'; 
   END LOOP;
end;

Error report -
ORA-00905: missing keyword
ORA-06512: at line 4
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @Naveen - from what you pasted in your comment above I can see that you still have no space before the 'to' in 'to ARCTOOLS212'.  Fix that and you will be good.

Comment: @BriteSponge - I have added the space but still same issue
BEGIN
FOR X in (select * from all_tables where owner in ('CRPDTA', 'CRPCTL'))
LOOP
    
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ' ||X.owner||'.'||X.table_name|| ' to ARCTOOLS212'; 
END LOOP;
END;
/

Comment: @Naveen - I have just cut/pasted your code, substituted a schema owner and run your code using DBMS_OUTPUT as I suggested and it works. This is what I used;   DECLARE
  c_sql  VARCHAR2(1500);
BEGIN
 FOR X in (select * from all_tables where owner in ('SCHEMA_OWNER'))
 LOOP
   c_sql := 'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ' ||X.owner||'.'||X.table_name|| ' to SCHEMA_GRANTEE';
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SQL- '||c_sql);
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE c_sql;
 END LOOP;
END;

Comment: @BriteSponge - Thanks, will check it tomorrow and update you.

Comment: @BriteSponge - Executed your code but still same issue.
Error starting at line : 8 in command -
DECLARE c_sql VARCHAR2(1500); 
BEGIN FOR X in (select * from all_tables where owner in ('CRPDTA', 'CRPCTL')) LOOP 
c_sql := 'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ' ||X.owner||'.'||X.table_name|| ' to ARCTOOLS212'; 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SQL- '||c_sql); 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE c_sql; 
END LOOP; 
END;

Error report -
ORA-00905: missing keyword
ORA-06512: at line 5
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @Naveen - The script works for me so as it doesn't work for you I suggest you approach this by writing it differently and adding bits in as you go, e.g. declare an explicit cursor, try another table owner, take the string used in the EXCEUTE IMMEDIATE and try to run it manually. Basically, break it down. Try other things.

Comment: @BriteSponge - 

i have run the below statement, spooled the file and executed the spool file.

SQL> select 'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ' || owner||'.'||table_name|| ' to user1;' from all_tables where owner in ('owner1','owner2') ;